# EXM html mail-opened tracking pixel does not contain alt attribute

Tags: exm

We are using EXM 3.4 and trying to improve our mail spam test scores and I found that mailtester tells that missing alt attribute on the mail-open tracking pixel gives -0.5 score.

[image]

I tried to disassemble some dlls and found that its hardcoded into HtmlMailBase abstract class `Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Messages.HtmlMailBase, Sitecore.EmailCampaign`and think there is no way to inject into any config to change that, am I right?

Adding empty `alt=""` attribute should fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that buried deep inside of EXM, they manually generate this link. I do think the proper solution is probably seeing if the EXM Team can make this image element a little more easily accessible or add in the alt attribute.  That being said, I did find a workaround. It might even be a hack!

## Workaround/Hack

There is one Pipeline that can be affected, where we can add in this alt attribute to this image tag before sending.

The pipeline to reference is **/sitecore/pipelines/SendEmail**.

In this pipeline, the processor "FillEmail" is what actually takes the Message Body and converts it into a email packet.  Putting a Processor, say called **AddAltAttribute** *before* **FillEmail** provides us a space to do some magic.

Below is the processor that I came up with to add the **alt** attribute to the `RegisteredEmailOpened` image.

### AddAltAttribute Processor

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines;
using Sitecore.StringExtensions;

namespace SitecoreHacker.Sandbox.EmailCampaign.Pipelines.SendEmail
{
    public class AddAltAttribute
    {
        public void Process(SendMessageArgs args)
        {
            if (args.EcmMessage == null)
                return;

            var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(args.EcmMessage.Body);

            var docNode =
                htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                    .Descendants("img");

            var foundElement = docNode.FirstOrDefault(node => node.HasAttributes && node.Attributes["src"].Value.Contains("RegisterEmailOpened"));

            if (foundElement == null)
                return;

            foundElement.Attributes.Add("alt", "");

            string result = null;
            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                htmlDoc.Save(writer);
                result = writer.ToString();
            }

            if (result.IsNullOrEmpty())
                return;


            //Set Back in Args
            args.EcmMessage.Body = result;
        }
    }
}
```

### Patch Config

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <SendEmail>
        <processor type="SitecoreHacker.Sandbox.EmailCampaign.Pipelines.SendEmail.AddAltAttribute, SitecoreHacker.Sandbox"
                   patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.Pipelines.SendEmail.FillEmail, Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm']" />
      </SendEmail>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### Considerations

- Putting too much, heavy logic in the `SendEmail` pipeline can have a negative effect on the speed of dispatches. Ensure that whatever logic you use, it is completely optimized.
- The above code is provided as an example. No performance tests were utilized.

Comment: It works ok, but the only doubt I have is that parsing DOM an HtmlDocument is quite heavy operation and takes long time to execute...

Comment: Hence my considerations.  I did try every which way all the way up to customizing DispatchTask. But ran into many issues trying to get this to work. This was the last point I could find that didn't include rewriting EXM.

Comment: Lets wait then for EXM fix in new versions :)